# mmenu doesn't link within the same page

Tags: mmenu

It looks like mmenu does not link to any ID on the same page. Perhaps I am doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated!

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Serhiicss/pen/dWvVwa)

```
<a href="#my-menu">Open the menu</a>

<div id="my-header"></div>
<div id="my-content"></div>
<div id="my-footer"></div>

<nav id="my-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#my-header">Pink</a></li>
    <li><a href="#my-content">Orange</a></li>
    <li><a href="#my-footer">Tomato</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.mmenu.frebsite.nl" target="_blank">External link works</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Did you set the 'mmenu' setting so the pagescroll works correctly? So, after clicking on the link in 'mmenu' to scroll through the page?
I have #anchors at the Bootstrap nav pills, but pagescroll not working. After click on the link is 'mmenu' closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for the page-scroll-addon: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/addons/page-scroll.html